# How to correctly add JVM System properties flag

Tags: java, apache, solr, jvm

In the Solr logs I see error -

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Serialization support for 
org.apache.commons.collections.functors.InvokerTransformer is disabled for
security reasons. To enable it set system property 
'org.apache.commons.collections.enableUnsafeSerialization' to 'true',
but you must ensure that your application does not de-serialize
 objects from untrusted sources.
```

I am trying to add flag `-Dorg.apache.commons.collections.enableUnsafeSerialization=true`, but it don't help.
How to correctly enable this property? (I haven't access to the solrconfig.xml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add it to `SOLR_OPTS` environment variable or pass it directly to start script:

```
bin/solr start -Dorg.apache.commons.collections.enableUnsafeSerialization=true
```

As per [Configuring solrconfig.xml docs](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_0/configuring-solrconfig-xml.html):

> In general, any Java system property that you want to set can be passed through the bin/solr script using the standard -Dproperty=value syntax. Alternatively, you can add common system properties to the SOLR_OPTS environment variable defined in the Solr include file (bin/solr.in.sh or bin/solr.in.cmd).

Comment: can you please make example, how to correctly add it to the SOLR_OPTS?

Comment: @Bookin modifying env variables depends on your operating system

Comment: Yeah, I am trying use `-D` parameter, but looks like it not help